# addEventListener() when the id isn't specified

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

this to call each of the top menu

```
var arrayTop=document.getElementById("topmenu").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0;i<arrayTop.length;i++){
  document.getElementById(arrayTop[i].id).addEventListener("click",topMenu,false);
}
```

the HTML

```
<div id="topmenu">
  <a id="help" href=#><span>Help</span></a>
  <a id="frum" href=#><span>Forum</span></a>
  <a id="home" href=#><span>Home</span></a>
</div>
```

but,how to apply addEventListener() when the id isn't specified?
since some of the elements will have the same id. so i'll change the id attribute to be

```
<div id="topmenu">
  <a mnuid="help" href=#><span>Help</span></a>
  <a mnuid="frum" href=#><span>Forum</span></a>
  <a mnuid="home" href=#><span>Home</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Conceptually, you should not assign the same ID to more than one elements. Also, the attribute "mnuid" is not valid. Why don't you change that "mnuid" to "id" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the id.  You already have the elements from the call to `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var arrayTop = document.getElementById("topmenu").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < arrayTop.length; i++)
{
    arrayTop[i].addEventListener("click",topMenu,false);
}
```